# Bash script manipulate txt file to break line on specific number?

Tags: bash

I have a huge .txt file (8000000 characters, almost). They contain applications, all with the same ID number.

I wish to break to a new line in this txt file every time this specific application number occurs.

How would I go about this the smartest way? A bash script to run in Windows would be desirable, but what would be a good sequence of doing this with such a big file?

Sample input:

`12345 123451234512345AAAAAA 12345AAAA 08:00:00NAMENAME AA NAME NAME ADRESS 11 1122` - I wish for the script to split the text to a new line every time `12345` occurs, and include everything until the next `12345` occurs, if that makes sense!

However, some of the inputs may have no space inbetween... So it might be `12345123555123453413412345AAAAAA` .. how to handle this also?

Comment: `sed -i 's/application-id/&\n/g' some-file.txt`, maybe. Provide some sample input.

Comment: I added a sample input. I wish for the line to split at the specific number `12345` - it's the same one, always 5 digits long etc.

Comment: What is your sample output? For example, do you want every occurrence of `12345` to be replaced with a new line, or do you want a new line to be placed after every occurrence of `12345`?

Comment: The sample output is a linebreak every time `12345` occurs - because now, I have about 25000 applications on one line which as you can imagine is pretty messy. The sample contains 1 application, so I wish every line has 1 application - instead of 25000 applications in 1 line. If that makes sense :)

Comment: Try `sed -e 's/\b12345[ ]/\n&/g'` file or `sed -e 's/\b12345\b/\n&/g'`

Comment: I'll try this. Im a bit new to bash scripts - do I create a .sh file and just run it? where is the actually input? would that be after the `s/`/

Comment: You can just run `sed -e 's/\b12345\b/\n&/g' filename`  To test output to the screen or `sed -i ..` or `sed -i.bak` to edit the file in place (with `.bak` backup made of original) Since you have like 8000000 chars, you could just look at the first 10 lines with `sed -e 's/\b12345\b/\n&/g' filename | tail -n10`.

Comment: Cheers testing it later today.

Comment: **Note:** you final shell command to write a new file should be `sed -e 's/\b12345\b/\n&/g' filename | tail -n+2 > newfilename`. The `| tail -n+2` says to take all lines beginning at the 2nd line. (the `sed` command will leave 1-blank line at the beginning since it breaks on `\b` boundaries.

Comment: Will this also work if the `12345` is a part of a bigger string - i.e. `123456789` and `123459988` meaning the first 5 digits are the constant(and where we want to linebreak) but it might be present with additional digits afterwards?

Comment: Yes, here I like this as the final `sed -e 's/\s\(12345\)\b/\n\1/g' filename` You can use it with `-e` to check and `-i` or `-i.bak` to change the file in place. It leaves no blank line at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your input of some insanly long file with lines like:

```
$ cat filename.txt
12345 123451234512345AAAAAA 12345AAAA 08:00:00NAMENAME AA NAME NAME ADRESS 11 1122 12345 123451234512345AAAAAA 12345AAAA 08:00:00NAMENAME AA NAME NAME ADRESS 11 1122 12345 123451234512345AAAAAA 12345AAAA 08:00:00NAMENAME AA NAME NAME ADRESS 11 1122 12345 123451234512345AAAAAA 12345AAAA 08:00:00NAMENAME AA NAME NAME ADRESS 11 1122 12345 123451234512345AAAAAA 12345AAAA 08:00:00NAMENAME AA NAME NAME ADRESS 11 1122 12345 123451234512345AAAAAA 12345AAAA 08:00:00NAMENAME AA NAME NAME ADRESS 11 1122 12345 123451234512345AAAAAA 12345AAAA 08:00:00NAMENAME AA NAME NAME ADRESS 11 1122 12345 123451234512345AAAAAA 12345AAAA 08:00:00NAMENAME AA NAME NAME ADRESS 11 1122 12345 123451234512345AAAAAA 12345AAAA 08:00:00NAMENAME AA NAME NAME ADRESS 11 1122 12345 123451234512345AAAAAA 12345AAAA 08:00:00NAMENAME AA NAME NAME ADRESS 11 1122 12345 123451234512345AAAAAA 12345AAAA 08:00:00NAMENAME AA NAME NAME ADRESS 11 1122 12345 123451234512345AAAAAA 12345AAAA 08:00:00NAMENAME AA NAME NAME ADRESS 11 1122 12345 123451234512345AAAAAA 12345AAAA 08:00:00NAMENAME AA NAME NAME ADRESS 11 1122 12345 123451234512345AAAAAA 12345AAAA 08:00:00NAMENAME AA NAME NAME ADRESS 11 1122 12345 123451234512345AAAAAA 12345AAAA 08:00:00NAMENAME AA NAME NAME ADRESS 11 1122 12345 123451234512345AAAAAA 12345AAAA 08:00:00NAMENAME AA NAME NAME ADRESS 11 1122 12345 123451234512345AAAAAA 12345AAAA 08:00:00NAMENAME AA NAME NAME ADRESS 11 1122
```

You can use `sed -e 's/\s\(12345\)\b/\n\1/g' filename.txt` to break each line at the beginning of `'12345'` (alone and not part of another word), example:

```
$ sed -e 's/\s\(12345\)\b/\n\1/g' filename.txt
12345 123451234512345AAAAAA 12345AAAA 08:00:00NAMENAME AA NAME NAME ADRESS 11 1122
12345 123451234512345AAAAAA 12345AAAA 08:00:00NAMENAME AA NAME NAME ADRESS 11 1122
12345 123451234512345AAAAAA 12345AAAA 08:00:00NAMENAME AA NAME NAME ADRESS 11 1122
12345 123451234512345AAAAAA 12345AAAA 08:00:00NAMENAME AA NAME NAME ADRESS 11 1122
12345 123451234512345AAAAAA 12345AAAA 08:00:00NAMENAME AA NAME NAME ADRESS 11 1122
12345 123451234512345AAAAAA 12345AAAA 08:00:00NAMENAME AA NAME NAME ADRESS 11 1122
12345 123451234512345AAAAAA 12345AAAA 08:00:00NAMENAME AA NAME NAME ADRESS 11 1122
12345 123451234512345AAAAAA 12345AAAA 08:00:00NAMENAME AA NAME NAME ADRESS 11 1122
12345 123451234512345AAAAAA 12345AAAA 08:00:00NAMENAME AA NAME NAME ADRESS 11 1122
12345 123451234512345AAAAAA 12345AAAA 08:00:00NAMENAME AA NAME NAME ADRESS 11 1122
12345 123451234512345AAAAAA 12345AAAA 08:00:00NAMENAME AA NAME NAME ADRESS 11 1122
12345 123451234512345AAAAAA 12345AAAA 08:00:00NAMENAME AA NAME NAME ADRESS 11 1122
12345 123451234512345AAAAAA 12345AAAA 08:00:00NAMENAME AA NAME NAME ADRESS 11 1122
12345 123451234512345AAAAAA 12345AAAA 08:00:00NAMENAME AA NAME NAME ADRESS 11 1122
12345 123451234512345AAAAAA 12345AAAA 08:00:00NAMENAME AA NAME NAME ADRESS 11 1122
12345 123451234512345AAAAAA 12345AAAA 08:00:00NAMENAME AA NAME NAME ADRESS 11 1122
12345 123451234512345AAAAAA 12345AAAA 08:00:00NAMENAME AA NAME NAME ADRESS 11 1122
```

You can use the `sed -i.bak` option to change the file in place while creating a backup of the original in `filename.txt.bak` or you can omit the backup with `sed -i`. For testing you could use `sed -e ... | tail -n10` to look at the first 10 lines produced by the `sed` expression.

If you wanted a script where you provide the `filename` to search and the `token` to break the line on, you could do something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

[ -z "$1" -o -z "$2" ] && {  ## validate 2 arguments given
    printf "error: insufficient input, usage: %s file token\n" "${0//*\/}"
    exit 1
}

[ -f "$1" ] || {  ## validate the first is a filename
    printf "error: invalid filename '%s' (file not found).\n" "$1"
    exit 1
}

## call the sed command
sed -e "s/\s\(${2}\)\b/\n\1/g" "$1"
```